# how to solve auto id generate?

Tags: c#, automation, windows-forms-designer

auto-generate id code is not working this is the code

```
private void Item_txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-H5D0DBC\SQL2019;Initial Catalog=system;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("Select isnull Max(Item)+1 from syst", myConn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ada.Fill(dt);
        Item_txt.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        Item_name_text.Focus();
        this.ActiveControl = Item_name_text;
    }
```

Comment: Usually an autonumber identity column will be used in SQL, rather than generating an id in code. The functionality in SQL Server ensures you won't get duplicates, etc.

Comment: The [sql server isnull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a function, you are missing the parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Cleptus is correct, your SQL is malformed. Most likely the SQL you wanted was:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Item), 0) + 1 FROM syst
```

Since this query returns a single row and column, you can get the result quite simply using `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`:

```
string sql = "SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Item), 0) + 1 FROM syst";
int newID = 0;
using (var myConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConn);
    myConn.Open();
    newID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}

Item_txt.Text = newID.ToString();
Item_name_text.Focus();
this.ActiveControl = Item_name_text;
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I have found to to this is by building a proper DBContext with the table configurations:

Here is an example:

SQL Script for Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Sku] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [UseAsGenericProduct] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsTaxExempt] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsGiftCard] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CostPrice] [money] NULL,
    [SuggestedSellingPrice] [money] NULL,
    [UnitsInStock] [int] NULL,
    [ReorderLevel] [int] NULL,
    [IsRefundable] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductV2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The entity should look something like this:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool UseAsGenericProduct { get; set; }
    public bool IsTaxExempt { get; set; }
    public bool IsRefundable { get; set; }
    public bool IsGiftCard { get; set; }
    public decimal? CostPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? SuggestedSellingPrice { get; set; }
    public int? UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public int? ReorderLevel { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateOn {get; set; }
    public bool IsActive {get; set; }
}
```

We will now look at how to write this table as a Configuration file in Visual Studio:

We start off by creating a configuration file:

```
 public class ProductConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> entity)
    {
        entity.ToTable("Product");
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).UseIdentityColumn().ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); // THIS IS THE LINE THAT HANDLES AUTO GENERATE

        entity.Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
         .IsRequired()
         .IsUnicode(false)
         .HasColumnType("datetime")
         .HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);

        entity.Property(e => e.LastUpdatedOn)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);

        entity.Property(e => e.Description)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        entity.Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        entity.Property(e => e.Sku)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsUnicode(false);

        entity.Property(e => e.IsGiftCard)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("bit");

        entity.Property(e => e.IsTaxExempt)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("bit");

        entity.Property(e => e.CostPrice)
            .HasColumnType("money");
        
        entity.Property(e => e.SuggestedSellingPrice)
            .HasColumnType("money");            
    }
}
```

Now in our DbContext :

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
     public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductConfiguration ());
     }
}
```

Then when you are querying the DB:

you can do it like follows:

```
MyDbContext.Products.Add(new Product{...});
```

Then your product will have an auto generated Id